# full size Google map doesn't fit to screen size

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, screen-resolution

We are building a web application with google map that covers all the main page.
It looks great but when I open it on another computer, with slightly different resolution or screen size, the map size does not change accordingly.

I tried working with "%" instead of "px" but it is even worse and the map disappears.

I found some solutions that use "!important" but it didn't work for me, can't figure out why.

Here is my CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) for the map:

```
#google-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #e7eaf0;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #google-container {
        height: 300px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
    #google-container {
        height: 710px;
    }
}

#cd-google-map {
    position: relative;
}

#cd-google-map address {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 1em 1em;
    background-color: rgba(211, 104, 104, 0.9);
    color: white;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-size: 0.8125rem;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    #cd-google-map address {
        font-size: 15px;
        font-size: 0.9375rem;
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Here is my html (the map is being built in the main.js file):

```
<section id="cd-google-map">
    <div id="google-container"></div>
    <div id="cd-zoom-in"></div>
    <div id="cd-zoom-out"></div>
    <div id="addNewReviewButton" ng-controller="NavCtrl">
        <button style="border-color: transparent; background-color: transparent;">
            <ng-md-icon icon="add_circle" style="fill: #d43f3a" size="120" ng-click="addNewReview()"></ng-md-icon>
        </button>
    </div>
</section>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAl8UrwCupLjkdVfx_IXugrryC8ES32Cz8&language=iw&?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Here is an image of how it looks on my device, when on others it fits perfectly:
[image]

Comment: can you post your html too?

Comment: I was struggling with this myself, hopefully you'll find some kind of solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just resolved it you need to change to:

```
height: 100vh;
```

and to make these following changes:

```
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Hope that help you as much it helped me.

Comment: Just replacing height: 400px;  with height: 50vh; worked for me.  Now my page fit the mobile device screen.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can use vw (viewport width) and vh (viewport height) instead of %
like :

```
height: 100vh;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your problem is this CSS:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #google-container {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

If you remove that, you can use percentage sizing (or vh/vw sizing)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ut7u0m3r/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You may use absolute positioning to fit the whole container to the edges of the browser:

**Markup**

```
<div class="map">
     the map is here ...
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.map{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This gives you a fullscreen map layout.
parent is set to relative, then the IFRAME is treated as child of that parent with `position:absolute` values.

`padding-bottom: (height*100)/width`;

**for e.g.:**

`padding-bottom: 56.22%  /*(768*100)/1366) - common screen resolution.*/`

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 56.22%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3774.2135216027964!2d72.83238461524519!3d18.921940761713312!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x3be7d1c73993eebd%3A0x9e8c8bfbd74a913a!2sGateway+of+India%2C+Apollo+Bandar%2C+Colaba%2C+Mumbai%2C+Maharashtra+400001!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1450701184011"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```